# How do you set the phase space area for the simulation of a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, simulations, phase-space

I am simulating a quantum system where I am evolving a Wigner function so i have a grid where I have the X-vaues and P-values. Now, I want to run the simulation for a phase space area of $\hbar$ or some multiple of it. How do I choose the ranges for x and p?

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked here. Could you re-read the question and try to clear it up?

Comment: i am trying to recreate a simulation and so i have a meshgrid and a distribution function. butit is said that the phase space are is hbar. i dont know how to set that up? likedo i take the x limits and p limits in the grid such that they follow some relation?